# How does localhost get its ID number in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How does localhost get its ID number in asp.net?

I have a question about ASP.NET and running test web sites locally.
I have written two asp.net web sites for testing purposes. One works and the other one fails.  The one that fails does not give any useful diagnostic information.

Can you tell me how these id’s are generated that are alongside the localhost: url?

[image]

Comment: These are port numbers, not IDs. Sounds like you miss important technical background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This number is the port number on which your local development server is listening.
It is generated "randomly" when you start the project.
You can set it manually if you like. Have a look at "[How to: Specify a Port for the Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx)".

Comment: Please don't post old MSDN links. Try posting the link without the (v=v.xx) part.

Answer (score 1):

See: [How to: Specify a Port for the Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx)

Inside the project settings Web tab in Visual Studio.

[image: Web Tab]

Comment: I cannot find it; at least not yet.

Comment: I found it, it is in a different location with Visual Studio 2010, perhaps.  Or it is accessable in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `Port Number`. When ASP.NET development server is used to host a page or application (i.e. when your run the application directly from you Visual Studio). This Post Number is assigned randomly.

You can also specify a port number to be consistent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28VS.80%29.aspx

Also, you will notice that you don't see these port number when you host your application using IIS because by default port 80 is assigned to IIS.